# HTTPS vs HTTP for SEO

Tags: seo, https

I've read than in 2014, Google will reward HTTPS sites in ranking.
In the other hand, I have also read that HTTPS is slower than HTTP.

So, in my site, I just have a few HTTPS pages, so my question is: Should I put all my site in HTTPS, or just the few pages I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a myth that HTTPS is slower than HTTP. Yes, your site may be a little bit slower but this can be prevented. Please check out [this](http://blog.httpwatch.com/2009/01/15/https-performance-tuning/) article for suggestions.

From SEO perspective, it's definitely better to use HTTPS. As you've already said, Google will reward sites using HTTPS. You might want to read the [official blog article](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.nl/2014/08/https-as-ranking-signal.html) from Google for more information about this.

Comment: If your site is a little bit slower then, no, HTTPS being slower is not a myth and, in fact, they are. However, as you said, Google gives a slight tip of the hat to HTTPS sites and the slight slowdown is worth the effort.

Comment: @Rob As I've already said, HTTPS is indeed a little bit slower but there's not a very big difference in speed - and it can be prevented.